# 200 ACT HTTP Response

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, mod-jk

I have a bunch of **Tomcat 8.0.15, Apache 2.2.29 and mod_jk 1.2.40** (win2003 serv)

In the http response status text I get **"200 ACT"**. Is not a standart http 1.1 rfc **"200 OK"**.
It doesn't  affect on a normal work, but response is really weird...

Also tested on a clean-default configuration tomcat8-apache2.4(win7) - the same result.

In the mod_jk debug log we have:

```
 [debug] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1403): received from ajp13 pos=0 len=69 max=8192
    [debug] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1403): 0000    04 00 C8 00 03 41 43 54 00 00 02 00 0D 43 61 63  - .....ACT.....Cac
```

Normal response is like:

```
[debug] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1403): received from ajp13 pos=0 len=100 max=8192
[debug] ajp_connection_tcp_get_message::jk_ajp_common.c (1403): 0000    04 00 C8 00 02 4F 4B 00 00 04 00 04 45 54 61 67  - .....OK.....ETag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rainer Jung has fixed this in the 8.0.17 Tomcat release.

Explanation: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1645245

Patch:

```
--- java/org/apache/coyote/ajp/AjpProcessor.java        (revision 1645245)
+++ java/org/apache/coyote/ajp/AjpProcessor.java        (working copy)
@@ -1388,6 +1388,7 @@

         response.setCommitted(true);

+        tmpMB.recycle();
         responseMsgPos = -1;
         responseMessage.reset();
         responseMessage.appendByte(Constants.JK_AJP13_SEND_HEADERS)
```

Is working now, Already tested.